# Excel VBA - Paste to visible cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a template that's linking to external source.

My predecessor created it and that for 'easiness' on the eye, he/she created it by skipping a row. i.e. row 1 then row 3, row 5, row 9, row 13 etc HAS FORMULA, whereas in between those mentioned rows are just DEFAULT EMPTY CELL.

I've created a vba that opens the workbook and copy the sheet that I want.

If I were to use the code below, it's running very slowly, and for some reason, it loops more than once.

```
for each cell in usedrange
if cell.hasformula = true and instr(cell.formula, "SUMIF") > 0 then
      cell.formulaR1C1 = "='\\tel\folder1\folder2\[xlsheet.xlsx]SheetName'!RC
   end if
next cell
```

Therefore, what I've done is to actually assign it once, copy it and then paste to the respective cells (as shown below).

```
Workbooks(desWB).Sheets(maxSheet + 1).Range("J5").FormulaR1C1 = fullPath
Workbooks(desWB).Sheets(maxSheet + 1).Range("J5").Copy
Workbooks(desWB).Sheets(maxSheet + 1).Range("J6:J12,E48:J55,E57:J58,E61:J79,E84:J93,E96:J96,E99:J103").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
```

The latter method works and it's definitely much faster than the first. However, now I am facing a situation where due to the setup of the template, some rows have formulas and some doesn't, and it goes to thousands of rows. The skipping of rows too sometimes is not an increment of 2, it could be 3, 5 etc.

So am wondering if there's a way that's more effective and efficient to:

- Look at the used range
- If range has formula AND formula has 'SUMIF'
- Change the formula to something else
- Else SKIP and check next cell

Comment: If the leftmost cell of a row is blank then does that meant the entire row should be skipped?

Comment: That's right...when that row is blank, the whole row is blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to process rows where the first cell in that row has a non-empty cell value then you should iterate the `Range`s rows *and* columns and skip the rows when the first cell fails the test.

Your current code that uses a `For Each cell in range` approach will still keep processing cells in an empty row - which is redundant.

You can use code like below to skip the blank rows and only apply conditional logic to rows where you are confident that some cells have the formula you want to update. In the example, I use `Range("C4:E10")` but you can substitute for the `Range` that works for you depending on your workbook structure.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    'could pass in UsedRange of the sheet...
    IterateRange ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C4:E10")
End Sub

Sub IterateRange(rng As Range)

    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim intX As Integer
    Dim intY As Integer

    'iterate all cells in range
    For intX = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        For intY = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
            'get a cell
            Set rngCell = rng.Cells(intX, intY)
            'check if cell is blank or empty
            If IsEmpty(rngCell.Value) Or rngCell.Value = "" Then
                'skip the rest of the columns in this row and goto next row
                Exit For
            Else
                'this row has non-empty cells - do something
                Debug.Print rngCell.Address
                'some other test
                If rngCell.HasFormula And InStr(1, rngCell.Formula, "SUMIF") Then
                    'update formula...
                    Debug.Print rngCell.Formula
                End If
            End If
        Next intY
    Next intX

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Robin...I haven't tested it yet, since I'm trying to put incorporate 'IterateRange' into my existing sub.

for the 'Debug.Print rngCell.Formula', is there a way to incorporate to my existing  sub? Would this be correct? Workbooks(desWB).Sheets(maxSheet + 2).rngCell.FormulaR1C1 = fullPathConsol   fullpathConsol is from my existing Sub?

Comment: I put the `Debug.Print rngCell.Formula` as a placeholder. You could replace that with you logic to update the cells `FormulaR1C1` property. I think there's a typo in your original question (no closing double quote) so I left doing this as something for you to do :) Basically once you know you want to do something with that cell - you can replace the `Debug.Print` statement.

Comment: Thanks Robin! Will look into it and reps up to you. And if it's the answer I'm looking for, I'll put a check mark on it.

Comment: So I've added a few lines.
fullPathConsol = "='" & Workbooks(desWB).Sheets("Get2017BudgetFiles").Range("A" & x).Value & "\[" & Workbooks(desWB).Sheets("Get2017BudgetFiles").Range("B" & x).Value & ".xlsx]Consol'!RC"
maxSheet = Workbooks(desWB).Sheets.Count
                    Workbooks(desWB).Sheets(maxSheet).rngCell.FormulaR1C1 = fullPathConsol

And I got an error message 'Object doesn't support this property or method' on the last line of the code which is Workbooks(desWB).Sheets(maxSheet).rngCell.FormulaR1C1 = fullPathConsol

Comment: Probably you don't need `Workbooks(desWB).Sheets(maxSheet)` in front of `rngCell` because `rngCell` already has been defined.

Comment: That's right!

So have tested it, and it's taking me approximately 4 minutes just to loop the cells, as I have just a little over 5000 rows of cells to 'loop' including the blank rows.

Is there a way to make it much more faster? Reason I asked is that I have 32 'sheets' that I need to copy and change those formulas

Answer (score 0):

Code line to execute:

```
Range("A1:A10").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = "1"
```

'This line send 1 to Visible Cells in A1:A10 range